# What was with Ron Perlman's character's nose obsession in Cronos?

Tags: character, analysis, cronos

In Guillermo del Toro's 1993 Bi-lingual first film, ***Cronos***, Ron Perlman's character Angel has an obsession with his own nose. He plans on getting rhinoplasty, and is seen in every scene doing something in that regard. The first time he's asking the main character and his daughter's opinion on noses. Then he's listening to pre-op surgery advice tapes. Then his nose gets broken and bandaged and then broken again.

But what is with the obsession? What is the meaning of it in the film? Or was it simply a sight gag?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's been so long since I've watched this wonderful film, but I will attempt to answer.

My feeling is that it was used to show his character's shallowness. The themes of the movie are quite profound, and the grandfather ultimately sacrifices himself for love of humanity, and specifically his grand-daughter.

Thus, presenting a shallow villain is a great juxtaposition.